# Custom dictionary for word removing in R

Tags: r, dictionary, tm

I'd like to create a custom dictionary of word to be removed into a Corpus. I'm using the `tm_map` command.

I'd like to start from a .txt file (like *word1,word2,word3*; file.txt), import it in R and transform it in a vector to put inside the following code:

```
tm_map(corpusname, content_transformer(removeWords(file.txt))
```

I find that writing vectors it's highly time consuming.

Comment: And where exactly do you struggle? You can certainly read in your txt file into R and convert it to a character vector as an input to your `removeWords` function.

Comment: You can use the **quanteda** package. It implements the `select_tokens()` function which helps doing your exact task. Read more [here](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/tokens/tokens_select/)